# Android drawable folder

Tags: android

I am trying to do an android app, with this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs

In link he says: create res/drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator.xml file,
but when I am looking to drawable folder there is only five folders:

[image: (http://prntscr.com/3zx7kl)]

Where do I put the actionbar_tab_indicator.xml file?

Comment: You have to make a new folder under `/res`, call it `drawable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make new folder named '**drawable**' in **app\src\main\res**
Then put your actionbar_tab_indicator.xml file there.